# "Ending with" vs "ending in"

Tags: prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“End with” vs. “end in”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/end-with-vs-end-in)

In one of my letters, I used the phrase "card number ending with 5612". It was pointed out by our analyst that this was a grammatical mistake, the correct phrase was "card number ending in".

I was pretty much baffled. To demonstrate the phrase "ending with" is correct I offer the following example: "A sentence begins with a capital letter and ends with a period."

It would be incorrect to say "A sentence begins in a capital letter and ends in a period."

Neither would it be correct to say "My credit card begins in 5421 and ends in 5612."

I would really be grateful if you could provide me answers. Also, can you include the reference for your answers.