# are there other phrases set up like "end up ____-ing (gerund)" if so, what are they called?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, grammatical-case, gerund-phrases, nonfinite-verbs

I'm watching a documentary and this was said:

> "We believe they did intentional things that kept Gabriel in harm's way, and ultimately ended up in him dying"

The "him dying" part is what struck me as odd.

I know that "end up" (from [other questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206233/end-up-doing-something-vs-end-up-with-doing-something-vs-end-up-in-doing-somet) here) usually is accompanied by a gerund, but I'm wondering if there are other sentence structures like this in English, and what this is called?

Tyia!